# Add or delete rows to Oracle Apex DB with cancel option

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

I would like to request help for design something in Oracle Apex.

Our Apex users can add or delete new row to tables in a page. Also after they making addition they got cancel button to the whole page.
The cancel button suppose to bring everything to it's previous state. E.g delete added rows, un-delete deleted rows, undo change of rows..

My solution now is adding another column (Hidden) to the database, which handles the row state, but it's not clean, and not working perfectly.

I'll be happy for new ideas, whether is DB related or Apex related, Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using an Interactive Grid ? In the interactive grid a user can add row(s) but then cancel and the row(s) will not be saved to the database. It does what you describe but it requires almost no dev work.

Comment: @KoenLostrie The thing is, we might have many tables in one page, so we have general "cancel" button for the whole page, not only for this specific table.

Comment: Pls update your question. You did not mention multiple tables, you say "a table". Also, what exactly is "Cancel" ? Is it revert last transaction ? Revert last x transactions by that user ? What if another user has updated a rows since the current user has added it, can that be cancelled as well ? How are rows being added, is the page being submitted more than once ? How long can a user redo what he did ? Can he cancel something that he did yesterday ? That solution with the hidden column you describe - what does that do exactly ? I don't see how that would enabled this functionality

Comment: It is common practice to use APEX collections for this sort of thing.  Before first showing the page, populate APEX collections with a copy of the existing data from the real tables.  Let the user add, delete and update rows in the APEX collections.  The Save button would then invoke a process to make the corresponding changes to the real tables, and Cancel would just leave without making any changes,

Comment: @KoenLostrie I changed from 'table' to 'tables. Other then that the question is pretty clear, I specified the cancel option is done on the whole page, not on table.

Comment: @TonyAndrews Thanks We did use collections. it is really great. (How didn't we use it before??). You can put it as an answer here if you want, so I can mark it as "accepted answer".

Comment: @Izik I have promoted my comment to an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common practice to use APEX collections for this sort of thing. Before first showing the page, populate APEX collections with a copy of the existing data from the real tables. Let the user add, delete and update rows in the APEX collections. The Save button would then invoke a process to make the corresponding changes to the real tables, and Cancel would just leave without making any changes,

Comment: Hi, It's been some time, but I wanted to ask if you got another solution when processing the collection on save. The scenario is this: the user inserts new rows to collection, editing some rows, and delete other rows. Now when we save it all, what the best and cleanest way to make all the changes in the real table? We did a pretty complex design which seems terrible to me. (add "status" column in collection that marking the row as "inserted/updated/deleted" and on global save check each row and handle it separately)